# inserting an array to MYSQL table field value w/relationship

Tags: mysql, database-schema, foreign-key-relationship

I am looking to place an array into a table field value using a sql statement.

I have two tables

```
 table1 - state
+---------------------+
 stateId | statename
+---------------------+

 table2 - manager
+---------------------+
 stateId
+---------------------+
```

I have a relationship with these two fields

If a manager handles multiple states, what would be the correct architecture for my database?

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the manager's states in the manager table. Instead, use a third table to store the state-manager relations. Something like this:

```
 table1 - state
+---------------------+
 stateId | statename
+---------------------+

 table2 - manager
+---------------------+
 managerId | managername
+---------------------+

 table3 - state_managers
+---------------------+
 managerId | stateId
+---------------------+
```